# Can I pass a Javascript array as a generic Collection in Rhino?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'd like to be able to pass a JavaScript array to a Java method that expects a `Collection`.  It seems really ham-fisted to write

```
var wrapper = new Packages.java.util.ArrayList();
wrapper.add("one");
wrapper.add("two");
// etc
new MyJavaThing(wrapper);
```

It works, but I'm scripting in JS to get *away* from being so damn verbose.  Ideally I'd just call

```
new MyJavaThing(["one", "two"]);
```

but the [NativeArray](http://stderr.org/doc/rhino-doc/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/NativeArray.html) doesn't implement `Collection` or any of its subinterfaces.

Comment: As a note, both Jython and JRuby handle this the way I want it to happen, i.e. array-to-List conversion happens transparently.

Answer (score 1):

It's not my favorite solution but it's possible to use

```
new MyJavaThing(java.util.Arrays.asList(["one","two"]));
```

You still have to be aware that the thing you're calling is in the Java World, but at least it's a reasonable one-liner.